# Dynamic initial state in React Redux based on props from React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

Is there any way to have a dynamic initial state loaded into Redux? In my case, I'd like a certain variable in the store to be dependent on what route the user initially lands on.

Right now, my workaround is not to show any components until it's fully loaded. I check the `location.pathname` on `componentDidMount` and then set the variable based on that and also the `loaded` variable to true in the store but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: set the initial value to null or undefined in your `initialState`. in your connector's `mapStateToProps`, check for that case and use whatever default value your component needs. or you can probably do something custom in `createStore()` for that state object that sets the default.

Comment: @Derek oh perfect, didn't know about the ownProps second param, thanks!